# why I am getting error from the try condition?

Tags: python, pandas

```py
    string_features = []
    for j in main_labels2: 
        if df[j].dtype == "object":
            string_features.append(j)
    try:
        string_features.remove("Label")
    except:
        print("error!")
```

`main_labels2` array:

```py
main_labels2 = ["Flow ID","Source IP","Source Port","Destination IP","Destination Port","Protocol","Timestamp","Flow Duration","Total Fwd Packets",
   "Total Backward Packets","Total Length of Fwd Packets","Total Length of Bwd Packets","Fwd Packet Length Max","Fwd Packet Length Min",
   "Fwd Packet Length Mean","Fwd Packet Length Std","Bwd Packet Length Max","Bwd Packet Length Min","Bwd Packet Length Mean","Bwd Packet Length Std",
   "Flow Bytes/s","Flow Packets/s","Flow IAT Mean","Flow IAT Std","Flow IAT Max","Flow IAT Min","Fwd IAT Total","Fwd IAT Mean","Fwd IAT Std","Fwd IAT Max",
   "Fwd IAT Min","Bwd IAT Total","Bwd IAT Mean","Bwd IAT Std","Bwd IAT Max","Bwd IAT Min","Fwd PSH Flags","Bwd PSH Flags","Fwd URG Flags","Bwd URG Flags",
   "Fwd Header Length","Bwd Header Length","Fwd Packets/s","Bwd Packets/s","Min Packet Length","Max Packet Length","Packet Length Mean","Packet Length Std",
   "Packet Length Variance","FIN Flag Count","SYN Flag Count","RST Flag Count","PSH Flag Count","ACK Flag Count","URG Flag Count","CWE Flag Count",
   "ECE Flag Count","Down/Up Ratio","Average Packet Size","Avg Fwd Segment Size","Avg Bwd Segment Size","faulty-Fwd Header Length","Fwd Avg Bytes/Bulk",
   "Fwd Avg Packets/Bulk","Fwd Avg Bulk Rate","Bwd Avg Bytes/Bulk","Bwd Avg Packets/Bulk","Bwd Avg Bulk Rate","Subflow Fwd Packets","Subflow Fwd Bytes",
   "Subflow Bwd Packets","Subflow Bwd Bytes","Init_Win_bytes_forward","Init_Win_bytes_backward","act_data_pkt_fwd",
   "min_seg_size_forward","Active Mean","Active Std","Active Max","Active Min","Idle Mean","Idle Std","Idle Max","Idle Min",**"Label"**,"External IP"]
```

I am working on a dataset which contains a netflow analysis. Now the labels for this dataset that is `df` is in the `main_labels2` array. So the `Label` is a property/column in the dataset that I want to remove. It contains categorical data.So what happens is that whenever the try condition is tested it prints an "error!" always. Please tell what I am doing wrong. This is the first time i am asking question on stack overflow so do tell if i posted the question in a wrong way.

Comment: The trouble with `except:` is that it hides the real problem.  When developing, it's better to catch only exceptions you expect and know how to handle.  For others, let the exception happen so that you can analyze the traceback and fix the code.

Comment: It's likely that `string_features` does not contain`"Label"` because your `if` test does not do what you think it does. Follow @snakecharmerb 's advice and don't suppress the error that would tell you this.

Comment: Please use correct formatting for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter out `Label`, you can do something like:

```
string_features=[]
for j in main_labels2: 
    if df[j].dtype=="object":
        if j != 'Label':
            string_features.append(j)
```

With pandas you can also do:

```
string_features = (df
                  .select_dtypes(include='object')
                  .drop('Label', axis=1)
                  .columns.tolist())
```

Comment: what i want to add string_features list are the non-numeric data. If i am using this solution or even mine i dont know why but the string_features only contains one column which is ActiveMax. it does add the others that also have non-numeric values. and yes the Label column is to be removed